# Need a solution for backups

Tags: server, lubuntu, backup, sync

Well,

I'm done with a OwnCloud server running in Lubuntu 16.10, all working fine, but I would like to backup this server to an external hdd, mostly to prevent rasonware or file deleting.
My desire schema:

- Clone all server, sda to sdb
- Automatically
- Weekly

Questions:

- I'm thinking about using TimeShift and save snapshots of the server to the external hdd. If the server got corrupted (can't boot to OS) can I still restore it?
- Grsync would do any help?
- Can you please enlight me with some advise, methods or best practices?

I'm quite new to this Ubuntu world, I'm learning a lot in this few days. Thanks.

Comment: You may want two backup methods: 1. Once in a great while you clone the whole drive with Clonezilla. This is done manually, when booted from another drive (a Clonezilla drive); 2. Backup the important parts of the system with a backup tool (or home-made script).  This can be done automatically (daily or weekly), for example via an entry in crontab.

Comment: I finally went with Macrium Reflect. It's a Windows backup program that can deal with Ubuntu partitions.